# Spam Content Serving from old cached version of site?

Tags: hacked, spam

I've been doing WP for over a decade now, and have fixed / remediated my share of hacks. However this one really has me stumped..

I have a site running on updated, patched, and pretty darn secure WordPress. For context, it used to NOT be so secure before I took over hosting it. It used an old theme, Experon Pro (this will come into play later) before I rebuilt it in 2020.

Now to the hack -- The site has a BUNCH of URLs that are complete spam, mostly about CBD oil and such. They look like blog posts, sorta. Except they're referencing the OLD template Experon Pro. They're browseable URLs, return 200 and all that. However, these posts / spam content:

1. Do not exist in the WordPress database anywhere
2. Are not referenced in htaccess or similar
3. Are not redirected using some altered file or hacked plugin.

The thing that's got me wondering is that the posts are using the old template (although, to be fair, all the links to the CSS files, JS files, etc that that old template would've loaded 404.)

It's almost like there's an old cache of URLs that are being served up from the domain. There are NO cache plugins running, only PageSpeed. And I've cleared and disabled PageSpeed like a thousand times.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this? I've scanned the entire file system and database for any mention of this content, and have come up completely empty.

Is it possible that their DNS or maybe some old CloudFlare integration got hacked, and the domain is serving up spam ONLY from certain subfolders? All of the spam posts have a subfolder, and then the spam post's name.. Such as /cbd-topicals/spammy-post-name-here

Any ideas at all? I'm desperate!

Comment: Very odd.  I suspect there is a script running in the rebuilt site that is pulling this content in from an external source if the site was compromised that badly when you received it.  You are searching for unique strings in the spam which won't be found in your DB or files if my suspicion is correct.  Have you tried the old standard theme switch and plugin deactivation?  Ensure your WP core files are new and untainted and activate one of the core themes.

Comment: The weird thing is I can even "break" the site by tossing in some garbage into the htaccess, which throws a 500 error on every legitimate page. However, every spam page still serves. Additionally, the spam pages have an HTML structure exactly like the OLD theme, which doesn't even exist on the server anymore. I turned on Troubleshooting mode (all plugins and themes deactivated) and it still serves the spam. I'm stumped.. There ARE references to a CloudFlare in the HTML of the spam pages, which makes me think this junk is cached somewhere...